# Create a root password for PHPMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

PHPMyAdmin is giving me a message saying that the user (root) does not have a password.

So, how can I create one?

Comment: root user for mysql? or server root? phpmyadmin wouldnt need server root. why would it? you need to look into mysql user account and set that to phpmyadmin

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, I believe that I've solved the password configuration 'issue' - WampServer 2.2 - Windows 7.

The three steps that I did:

1. In the MySQL console set a new password. To make that:  `mysqladmin -u root password 'your_password'`
2. In `phpMyAdmin` click in users and set the same password to the user `root`.
3. Finally, set your new password in the `config.inc.php`. Don't change anything else in this file.

This worked for me. Good luck!

Daniel

Comment: After modifying config.inc.php file (step 3) you may need to restart your browser.

Answer (score 165):

Open phpMyAdmin and select the SQL tab. Then type this command:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('your_root_password');
```

Also change to this line in `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

To make phpMyAdmin prompts for your MySQL username and password.

Comment: This code simply denied me access to phpmyadmin. Can't access it right now.

Comment: I had to change this line also 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_root_password';

Comment: @malintha you don't need to store your password in that config file. If some one can read your `config.inc.php` file, then they can use it easily..

Comment: This is correct. More simply to access PhpMyAdmin with MySQL server's root password, as stated in this reply, modify `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']` to `= 'cookie` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';` , this will accept the MySQL' root password

Comment: quotes are required, took the liberty to fix it. If you think if wrong please correct them and Ill glad to put the correction in comment. Sorry and thanks for your answer, very helpful

Answer (score 56):

To create root password in PHPMyAdmin in UI easy way, you can follow simple steps below:

- Access phpMyAdmin with root account (no password) -> User accounts.

[image]

Click on root > Edit privileges

[image]

Then click on Change password

[image]

Enter your desired password -> Go

[image]

Logout and log-in again with new password

Comment: Not sure why everyone else is making it more complicated.  This works perfectly, is simple and answers the OP's question.

Comment: if you had your root account without a pwd then do not forget to add to your `config.inc.php`: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` or update `config.inc.php` cause otherwise you will get auth error on entering the admin

Comment: I get `#1819 - Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements` even though I have a very strong 128 bit password with a-Z 0-9 and special chars. It also says "extremly weak"

Answer (score 8):

PHPMyAdmin is telling you that your MySQL service is missing a root password. You can change it by accessing the MySQL command line interface. `mysqladmin -u root password newpass`

http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

Comment: well if he never created one it s even easier than resetting.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how can I insert that command in MySQL server? I mean, I've installed phpMyAdmin and Workbench too. Sorry if this is too "newbie question"...

Comment: Is the MySQL server running on your local machine? If so open the terminal or on windows run `cmd` and type it in there. After that you might need to reconfigure the PHPMyAdmin installation.

Answer (score 8):

Here the simple step that you can easily set phpMyAdmin Password.

1. Goto `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin` and find `config.inc.php` file
2. Open `config.inc.php` file in Text editor like Notepad++.
3. Find the line `$cfg['Servers'][$a]['auth_type'] = 'config';` in `config.inc.php` file.
4. Change the word `$cfg['Servers'][$a]['auth_type'] = 'config';` to `$cfg['Servers'][$a]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';` in `config.inc.php` file and Save the changes.
5. Now open browser and type `localhost/phpmyadmin`. Enter username is **root**. password is *null* means empty. you don't type anything leave blank and press GO button.
6. Now you can see **change password** link. please click that link.
7. Set your phpMyAdmin password and retype again and press GO button.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to phpmyadmin
2. Open user account section:

   [image: open user account section]
3. Use EDIT Privileges
4. Change password and username

   [image: change password and user name]
5. Add privileges for database

Answer (score 6):

On linux (debian 9) after resetting the mysql(Maria DB) root password,  you just have to edit the phpmyadmin db config file located at /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php

> ## gedit /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php  (as root)

Answer (score 5):

- Go to`http://localhost/security/index.php`
- Select language, it redirects to `http://localhost/security/xamppsecurity.php`
- You will find an option to change the password here

Answer (score 3):

I only had to change one line of the file `config.inc.php` located in `C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14`.

Put the right password here ...

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Put_Password_Here';
```

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the mysql user password problem - ERROR 1045: Access denied for user: 'root@localhost' (Using password: NO) - when I tried to do a do-release-upgrade on my operational system. So I corrected it in 2 steps.

Firstly, as I did not had access on phpmyadmin, so I followed the "Recover MySQL root password" step on the tutorial mensioned by ThoKra:
https://www.howtoforge.com/setting-changing-resetting-mysql-root-passwords

Secondly, with one of the users that I know the password, I made some password changes to the others users through phpmyadmin itself according to SonDang's information.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried `mysqladmin -u root password 'your_password'` and MySQL says `denied access`, you need to change the my.ini so that the value `password` is blank. then try `mysqladmin -u root password 'your_password'` again. It should change your password and open `my.ini` again and change the value `password` to the previous one.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the command you are looking for is `passwd`