# Can't login to my phpmyadmin on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have wamp server installed on my PC. I have used user: '`root`' and blank password till yesterday. But suddenly today I found out that I can't login to my phpmyadmin. I have checked my config.inc.php under `C:\wamp64\apps\phpmyadmin4.5.2` directory. I have added the code below:

```
    /* Servers configuration */
$i = 0;

$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; //What you want

/* Server: localhost [1] */
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Local Databases';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';

// Hidden databases in PhpMyAdmin left panel
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db'] = '(information_schema|mysql|performance_schema|sys)';

// Allow connection without password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;

// Suppress Warning about pmadb tables
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;

// To have PRIMARY & INDEX in table structure export
$cfg['Export']['sql_drop_table'] = true;
$cfg['Export']['sql_if_not_exists'] = true;

$cfg['MySQLManualBase'] = 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/';
/* End of servers configuration */
```

I edited the file with `['user'] ='root'` and `['password']=''` but no luck. Can please anyone help me with that? I don't know what's the problem. I have a lots of file hosted under my localhost. It would be a great help. Thanks in advance

Comment: first  you need to check which php version is currently running using `phpinfo();` then check the config file path there. change file and then save and then restart your server (xampp/wamp/lamp/mamp whatevrer you are using). restart is important

Comment: I have checked. I am using PHP version 7 and the config path for php.ini is C:\Windows.. Now what should I do?

Comment: change whatever you want to change and save and then restart your server

Comment: How I can change the path? But should I change that or should I have to work with config.inc.php file to fix the login problem?

Comment: Perhaps this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224431/create-a-root-password-for-phpmyadmin) could help in resetting the password?

Comment: Haven't helped. I can't access the phpmyadmin yet :(

Answer (score 0):

Might it be because you left the

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = '';
```

empty? Or is it an equivalent for root?

Comment: I don't know. I edited and replaced it with root but no luck :(