# XAMPP Error when i open PHPmyadmin

Tags: mysqli, phpmyadmin, xampp

I got this when I open phpmyadmin

> You are connected as 'root' with no password, which corresponds to the default MySQL privileged account. Your MySQL server is running with this default, is open to intrusion, and you really should fix this security hole by setting a password for user 'root'.

How can I fix this?

[image: password]

[image: error]

Comment: set password for phpmyadmin

Comment: from where i can edit

Comment: @RaomB Hi, i think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/12224464/7794860

Comment: @RaomB Check my answer

Comment: @AhmedGinani check the image even when i change it , it give me the same error, and i reload the privilege and it give me the same error. should i copy the generated one or the password i write ?

Answer (score 1):

Open phpmyadmin

Users Accounts > Select user "root" > Edit Privileges > Change password

Comment: check the image even when i change it , it give me thesame error, and reload the privilege. should i copy the generated one or the password i write  ?

Answer (score 0):

Run localhost->How-To Guides-> click on 'Reset the MySQL/MariaDB Root Password' -> Follow the steps

Comment: please click edit privileges corresponding to root  with password column 'YES' and then set the password.

Answer (score 0):

open phpmyadmin

Fire an update query

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('MyNewPass');
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how can i fire i cant access any thing

Comment: okay, not even phpmyadmin ? with username root with blank password ?

Comment: if you are having error :- can not connect : Invalid settings than you should locate your config.inc.php and comment it out controlhost,controlport,controluser and controlpassword.

Comment: c:\xamp\phpmyadmin.In that folder config.inc.php file would be present.