# Why i can't install phpmyadmin for the end?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am working on Ubuntu 16.10.
I use 10.1.26-MariaDB, it works perfect.

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.26-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

When I try to install PHPMyAdmin, I get the following error message:

```
 "ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)".
```

Why did this happen?

I enter the MySQL password during PHPMyAdmin installation, but it is not working.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944936/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-y) - basically you need to add the password with the `-p` flag when you start.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't quite understand where and when I need to enter a password? How can i know than mysql work without problem?

Comment: Phpmyadmin don't see the mysql, why this happend?

Comment: Perhaps [this might help too](https://askubuntu.com/q/852917/189361)?

Comment: [What about this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12254813/1270789)?

Comment: Ken Y-N It reason don't work for me. I write in _/etc/apache2/apache2.conf_    _Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache_, the problem in their question is **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

**, but my problem is **ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)**, i hope you see the difference. Thank you that responded

Comment: I do this step, when i install mysql for the first. Then i get error, that cannot access. because wrong password. Then i change the password with the method, than your get. I remember, the first time i get problem that __plugin unix_socket not loaded__ and i do this [https://www.versatilewebsolutions.com/blog/2015/05/dealing-with-mariadb-plugin-unixsocket-is-not-loaded.html]

Comment: Did you have a instruction, how to purge mysql and phpmyadmin and after that it works?

Answer (score -1):

I get the reason, i remove phpmyadmin and mariaDb, and install mysql-server, mysql-client, and it works!!!

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mariadb*
```

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

Remove all that start whith mariadb or mysql in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`

after remove all that start with mysql*

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove mysql*
```

sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean

after remove directory `/etc/mysql`

after remove directory `/var/lib/mysql`

after remove deb package for mariadb from `/etc/apt/sources.list`

after update

```
sudo apt-get update
```

sudo apt-get upgrade

after install mysql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
```

check if all it's ok

```
service mysql status
```

and install phpmyadmin

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

That's all, for me work!!!!